# Accessing Sharepoint from a WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm currently investigating SharePoint for our company as a means to make Excel processing accessible through our web application without relying on the Office Interop DLL files. (our sysadmin doesnt want to install Office on the production server, for good reason)

I'm aware that Sharepoint has an Excel Webservice that can be enabled and used by the application. The problem, if it is a problem, is that I need to make a class that wraps all the logic for transforming an Excel into HTML.
So I need to add the references to this webservice to the application.

But what if we need to deploy the application with a customer that has no SharePoint server available, will this cause a problem in the application? We will use checks to make stuff visible and invisible depending on whether a parameter is set, but I'm looking for a means to ensure that I can for example add the required references at runtime when I need them for Sharepoint.

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Question is not at all clear ..

Comment: I'll try to elaborate:

I have a SharePoint Service running "somewhere", could be localhost, could be a remote server in the network or could be an internet webservice. This location is different for each customer I wish to deploy my web application to.

Is it possible to add a reference to the Webservice from Visual Studio, but change the actuall destination of the webservice at runtime? or disable it all together if the client for example has no access to SharePoint.

Comment: Is it a custom Web Service hosted in the SharePoint web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you completely, but if you're just wondering about changing the URL of a web service(From say http://companyA.co/service.svc?wsdl to http://compB.co/serv.svc?wsdl), depending on where it is, that's easy as pie in .Net, basically just:

```
service.URL = "http://localhost:51112/Service1.svc?wsdl";
```